# Concurrent access to reflect.Value

Tags: go, concurrency

If I am writing a function to modify a variable's value dynamically, how would I go about making that function safe for concurrent use. For example, consider the following snippet:

```
func set(v, d interface{}) error {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    dst := reflect.ValueOf(d).Elem()

    if dst.Type() != val.Type() {
        return fmt.Errorf("incompatible types - %s %s", dst.Type(), val.Type())
    }
    dst.Set(val)
    return nil
}
```

This function will be called in the following manner:

```
i := 1
var j int
_ = set(i, &j)
```

Working code: https://play.golang.org/p/XjlHrDLFqd

How safe would it be to change `i` concurrently? `reflect.Value` [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) say the following:

> A Value can be used concurrently by multiple goroutines provided that
>   the underlying Go value can be used concurrently for the equivalent
>   direct operations.

Which leads me to believe that locking would be required. If so, where would the locking part go? Is it required to be maintained until the value (concrete) completely makes it through the reflection section? For example, in the above example, is it OK to keep a lock through out `set`'s execution?

Also, what are some underlying Go values that cannot be used concurrently (as mentioned in the docs bit above)?

Comment: No Go values are safe for concurrent read and write.

Comment: Start a goroutine with set(i, &j) and check with -race flag.  It should confirm no race condition.

Comment: A good rule of thumb in Go is if you're concerned about concurrent modification, you should take a long, hard look at your design and find a way to eliminate the concurrent access altogether - "Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating." See https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating

Sometimes unavoidable, but worth considering.

Comment: @Sridhar: there is a data race. The race detector is not infallible, but in this case there was a loophole through reflect and it will be fixed in go1.8.

Comment: Does that mean `encoding/json` and other similar packages that depend on reflection are also unsafe for concurrent use?

Comment: @JimB, can you please provide a [link to the issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues) to which you refer ?

Comment: @Sridhar: https://golang.org/issue/16281

Comment: @abhink: Nothing In Go is safe to use concurrently unless it's specifically documented as such, the use of reflection doesn't change anything. It would not be safe to encode/decode a value while it's being used concurrently, but that's no different than any other use in the language.